# 'Motion easing' effect in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, timer, easing

I need to increment an integer, but I want to ease the speed at which it's incremented. So say for example I have an int that is equal to 0, I would like this int to get to 100 eventually but increment progressively slower. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Are you using WPF (so that you can introduce animations?) Otherwise, a worker thread with a timer and a interval formula?

Comment: I am using WPF yes, if hcb's solution doesn't do what I'm after then I'll look at using a DispatcherTimer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hcb's answer works for 100, but a different value would require a different ease value.

A more generalised answer would be to use a sine, which means the ease would be the same no matter what final value you wanted, or however many steps you take.

```
private void EaseIn(int easeTo)
{
     for (int n = 0; n < easeTo; n++)
     {
          double degrees = (n * 90) / easeTo;
          double easedN =  easeTo * Math.Sin(degrees * (Math.PI / 180));

          Console.WriteLine("Eased n = " + easedN.ToString());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?:

```
for (int i = 0; i <=100; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(i);
}
```

Or like this:

```
float j = 1;
float ease = 0.005;
for (float i = 0; i <=100; i+=j)
{
    j -= ease;
}
```

Comment: take 0.005 instead of 0.02 though, or else it won't go to 100.